# Ошибка при установке Python приложения на Android 13

Tags: python, android, apk, buildozer

С помощью `buildozer` собрал файл `.apk` из Python. На Android 10 всё работает без проблем. Но на Android 13 не устанавливается, в эмуляторе `Android Studio` появляется ошибка:

> Error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

На физическом устройстве с Android 13 появляется ошибка:

> display_name column is null

Все решения, которые я нашел, связаны с JavaScript, в моем случае они неприменимы. Как пофиксить это в Python? Или в `buildozer`, если проблема в его настройках.

Comment: По первой ошибке - либо настройте эмулятор как ARM, либо сделайте сборку для x86.
Вторая относится скорее всего к file content provider, может быть специфичной для вашего конкретного телефона. В любом случае без деталей о самом приложении и модели телефона большего не скажешь.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Спасибо, но киньте пожалуйста ссылку на то, как делать сборки для ARM. Я в android studio пока плохо ориентируюсь, не могу это найти

Comment: Так вы для ARM и делаете их, раз на телефоне запускается. А для симулятора просто выберите system image с нужной архитектурой процессора: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#system-image

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja спрошу по другому - что вообще означает "настроить как ARM"? я то делаю как на скрине по ссылке. и если выбираю `Android 13.0` и `x86_64`, то появляется эта ошибка. На версии `Android 12.0` с той же архитектурой всё работает без замечаний

Comment: Так на скрине как раз arm64-v8a, ее и попробуйте.